# Get all metadata with cmis query in nuxeo

Tags: drupal, cmis, nuxeo

I'm using the drupal cmis api and a cmis query `SELECT+*+FROM+cmis:document+where+CONTAINS("blabla")`
to get document from my Nuxeo CAP version: 6.0` but when i get the result, i get the "Common metadata" but the "Metadata" are not send,and also 
for some of doc i have the correct dc:language but for others it's null but in nuxeo the language is correctly set 
i'm new on nuxeo can you help me ?
this is all metadata i receive for each file

> { ["links"]=> array(0) { } ["renditions"]=> array(0) { } ["properties"]=> array(35) { ["nuxeo:isVersion"]=> string(4) "true" ["cmis:objectTypeId"]=> string(12) "Documentblabla" ["nuxeo:isCheckedIn"]=> string(5) "false" ["dc:nature"]=> NULL ["dc:created"]=> string(29) "2014-11-18T21:52:39.456+01:00" ["dc:description"]=> NULL ["cmis:isLatestVersion"]=> string(4) "true" ["cmis:versionLabel"]=> string(3) "0.2" ["dc:rights"]=> NULL ["nuxeo:pathSegment"]=> string(12) "my_file.pdf" ["cmis:lastModifiedBy"]=> string(3) "user" ["cmis:createdBy"]=> string(13) "admin" ["dc:format"]=> NULL ["dc:valid"]=> NULL ["dc:title"]=> string(8) "my_file" ["dc:lastContributor"]=> string(3) "user" ["cmis:isLatestMajorVersion"]=> string(5) "false" ["cmis:name"]=> string(8) "my_file" ["nuxeo:lifecycleState"]=> string(7) "project" ["nuxeo:parentId"]=> NULL ["dc:creator"]=> string(13) "admin" ["cmis:creationDate"]=> string(29) "2014-11-18T21:52:39.456+01:00" ["dc:source"]=> NULL ["nuxeo:pos"]=> NULL ["dc:publisher"]=> NULL ["Relevance"]=> string(11) "0.285714298" ["cmis:objectId"]=> string(36) "id_of_doc" ["dc:issued"]=> string(29) "2015-04-16T14:29:05.082+02:00" ["cmis:baseTypeId"]=> string(13) "cmis:document" ["dc:modified"]=> string(29) "2014-11-23T18:57:06.097+01:00" ["dc:expired"]=> NULL ["dc:coverage"]=> NULL ["dc:language"]=> string(2) "en" ["cmis:description"]=> NULL ["cmis:lastModificationDate"]=> string(29) "2014-11-23T18:57:06.097+01:00" } ["uuid"]=> string(36) "http://chemistry.apache.org/**" ["id"]=> string(36) "id_of_doc" }

Comment: You would need to detail a bit what code you're using and what's going wrong. And what Nuxeo version you're using.

Comment: i use Nuxeo CAP version: 6.0. and when i make a cmis request like `/nuxeo/atom/cmis/default/query?q=SELECT+*+FROM+cmis:document`
i don't get all metadata

Comment: Please update the original question with this info instead of putting it in a comment. Also, please include part of the metadata you actually get and why you think `dc:language` is missing — I mean, did you set it beforehand? How?

Comment: i change the original question stangely now i receive the `dc:language` of certains document but not all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dc:language` of a document will be set if something set it beforehand. By default in Nuxeo it's not used, it's up to the application or the user to set it if needed.

Comment: i understand that, my second question is how can i receive all metadata with a cmis request

Comment: `SELECT *` will return all singled-value metadatas. If you want everything you'll have to explicitly fetch a given document.